# Unmet dependencies when installing Cockatrice

Tags: raspbian, debian, terminal, packages

I am somewhat new to Linux and raspi's in general, so it would be helpful to keep answers simple and well-versed. I am trying to install a debian package on my raspi (raspbian), which is [Cockatrice](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice). I ran into the following error when trying to install it via the command line:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cockatrice:amd64 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5-plugins:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5svg5:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.14) but it is not installable
                Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:3.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: liblzma5:amd64 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installable
                Depends: libprotobuf17:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5core5a:amd64 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5gui5:amd64 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5multimedia5:amd64 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5network5:amd64 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5sql5:amd64 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5svg5:amd64 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5websockets5:amd64 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: libqt5widgets5:amd64 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libstdc++6:amd64 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: zlib1g:amd64 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not installable
```

I tried running some commands to fix this error, but didn't seem to help:

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I also tried installing the individual packages, and I just get a message saying that the module is already installed, and it's version seems to be above the needed one for Cockatrice.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    libqt5svg5 is already the newest version (5.11.3-2).
    libqt5svg5 set to manually installed.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could someone help me resolve these errors, or find a way to install the package?

Comment: What's that AMD64 junk? Your raspberry has an ARMHF processor, do NOT add debian repos for other architectures that won't work and may break your system beyond repair.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install a package for a different processor architecture (AMD64) on the Pi (which is ARM). All the dependencies you see are AMD64 libraries. Because they are for a different processor, they will not run on the Pi. That is the reason why these dependencies are not in the repository for the Pi, and that they are not installable.

I have tried to find a Pi-version of the Cockatrice package, but I  have not been able to. You might try to install from source, but there have been some issues there as well; one of them is the expected compile time.